# Excel formula unable to create

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the data from the columns, **Name2** and **Name3**, in the single column below the data of the **Name1** column.

How should I do that?

[image]

Comment: It is Data* and not Date*, please consider it.

Comment: Try the `TOCOL` function.

Comment: Ok, have posted as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TOCOL` function, e.g.

`=TOCOL(A2:D5)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
=Name1&" "&Name2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the new **VSTACK** function.

It stacks ranges vertically and has the advantage that you can insert a heading.

```
=VSTACK("Combined Names",A2:A5,B2:B5,C2:C5)
```

[image]